# ExtJS: How to submit both: combobox value and text

Tags: extjs, combobox

ExtJS: How to submit both: combobox value and text using standardSubmit?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To submit the valueField, you must specify a `hiddenName` to create a hidden input field to hold the value of the valueField. You must also set `submitValue` to true

e.g.

```
var unitField = new Ext.form.ComboBox({
    id:'unitField',
    name: 'unit',
    submitValue : true,
    fieldLabel: 'Unit',
    store:unitStore,
    mode: 'remote',
    displayField: 'name',
    valueField: 'id',
    hiddenName : 'unitId',
    allowBlank: false,
    anchor:'95%',
    triggerAction: 'all'
});
```

So you get the value sent as unitId and the text as unit

Comment: For some reason I'm not getting unit in fields collection!? UnitId is fine.

Comment: If I comment out hiddenName : 'unitId', then I get 'unit' field, but no 'unitId' of course.

Comment: You also need to add submitValue: true to the config options. I have updated the answer.

Comment: From Docs - submitValue : Boolean
False to clear the name attribute on the field so that it is not submitted during a form post. If a hiddenName is specified, setting this to true will cause both the hidden field and the element to be submitted.

Comment: does this work for EXTJS 5? its not working for me but it is still available in the docs. Does this still exists at all?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to submit two values, you will need two fields.  If you want both fields to be controlled by one field, you should make one field hidden, and update it when the first is updated:

```
var hiddenField = new Ext.form.Hidden({
    name: 'comboDisplay'
});

var combo = new Ext.form.ComboBox({
    xtype: 'combo',
    // ...
    listeners: {
        select: function(combo, record) {
            hiddenField.setValue(record.data['display']);
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Your approach is correct. But this is not the complete answer yet. note that you also need a hiddenName if the valueField is to be submitted on standard submit which Milan mentions in his question.